# Handling searches while transitioning from MySQL to elastic search?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river, data-importer

I have a normal ec2 instance running elastic search , and synced up with mysql where data is imported from mysql into elasticsearch on a fixed interval .Approach used is to recreate index and reimport data after aa fixed interval .
What approach could be taken to handle the search while the reindexing and reimporting activities a still running?

Import is being carried through jdbc importer .

Any insights or guidance would be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

There's just one real way. You'd have to use aliases.

So that would be scenario:

- You create index with some date indication. Let it be `your_index-2015-11-23`
- You create an alias for it, let it be `your_index`
- Monday comes, you create a new index with different name
- You index data there
- Remove alias from first indice, add it to newly created one.

More here: [Index Aliases and Zero Downtime](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html)